# failed to open stream php error when loading stories from storyblok in twig

Tags: php, caching, twig, storyblok

Currently I am using the silex boilerplate from the storyblok github repository, where I load the stories via the `getStories` function.

My code looks like this:

```
{% 
   set reference = getStories(global('references_path'), 1, 0, options('{"filter_by[customer_name]":"' ~ item.customer_name ~ '"}')) 
%}
```

This code is called from another twig component in a loop.

For one "reference" I do get this error message:

> file_put_contents(../cache//c3RvcnlibG9rOnN0b3JpZXMvYTo0OntpOjA7czoxMDoiRXJkZ2FzIE/DliI7aToxO3M6MTE6ImRlL3Byb2pla3RlIjtpOjI7aToxO2k6MztzOjM6ImZzcCI7fQ==):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /webapp/vendor/apix/cache/src/Files.php

Seems to be an Issue with the cache.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path which will be generated in your case contains a `/`. So PHP can't create the file because it would be in an not existing folder.

We can see that this issue is in the `Files.php` of the `Apix/Cache` we are using to allow different caching options for the silex boilerplate. Nevertheless, we've found a way to fix this issue by now - but we will create a new pull request for the `Apix/Cache` so it will check for `/` before saving.

For you this means:

```
composer update
```

to install our new [php-client](https://github.com/storyblok/php-client) version [v1.1.11](https://github.com/storyblok/php-client/releases/tag/1.1.11).